# Can I change my eye colour temporarily?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

I was wondering if I could lighten my eyes using honey and then get them to be from brown to a blue then change them back to brown using surgery when I'm older.Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't as it is **prohibited** in Islam to change anything in your looks for the purpose of increasing your beauty or improving your appearance. It is actually prohibited for any reason except for treating an illness or for fixing a deformation.

The change of your natural eyes color is included in changing the figure that Allah created you.

Whether it was by natural remedies or not, the result still would be the same.

And in your case, it can't be considered temporarily since you would need surgery in order to remove what you have changed.

Allah Mighty said in [Surah AL-Nisa (4) — Verse (119)](https://quran.com/4/119):

In Arabic (the exact wording):

> وَلَأُضِلَّنَّهُمْ وَلَأُمَنِّيَنَّهُمْ وَلَآمُرَنَّهُمْ فَلَيُبَتِّكُنَّ آذَانَ الْأَنْعَامِ **وَلَآمُرَنَّهُمْ فَلَيُغَيِّرُنَّ خَلْقَ اللَّهِ ۚ** وَمَن يَتَّخِذِ الشَّيْطَانَ وَلِيًّا مِّن دُونِ اللَّهِ فَقَدْ خَسِرَ خُسْرَانًا مُّبِينًا

In English (in what it means):

> And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the ears of cattle, **and I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah.** And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss.

[Source](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/312682/)